# Change all text color inside brackets within a string php

Tags: php, text, preg-match

I am trying to change the text color within a string identified by brackets or any special character for that matter.. Say I have this string -

```
$text = 'Hello [how are you?]';
```

How can I change the color of the text that is just in the brackets?

I tried preg_match but am not doing it right..

```
$new_text = preg_replace('/(^|\s+)[([0-9a-zA-Z]+)](\b|$)/', '$1<span style="color:red;">#$2</span>', $text);
```

Comment: Try `preg_replace('/\[([^][]+)]/', '<span style="color:red;">#$1</span>', $text)`

Comment: So, my solution works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need a simple regex for this. [ + any character + ]. And you only need to replace the contents in the brackets so you can use () capturing groups to encapsulate the changeable text.

```
$new_text = preg_replace('/\[([^\]]+)\]/', '<span style="color:red;">$1</span>', $text);
```

**EDIT:**

Modified the regex. Rather than match all (Which would match a second occurrence of a `]`) I match everything up until the first occurrence of `]`

Better still as @msg states in the comments: Regex can be : `/\[(.*?)\]/`

Comment: You could have used the 'ungreedy' (`U`) modifier or just `.*?`.

Answer (score 2):

Even if there's an answer already, let me break down the problems in your regex:

- The character class in your original regex doesn't include `?` or whitespace. It can't contain punctuation or hypenation either.
- The outer brackets aren't scaped so instead of your intended *"anything betweet square brackets"* the engine is interpreting it as a character class (a list of valid characters to match) and then throwing a syntax error.
- You are using capturing groups as your anchors (it works because you took them into account in your replacement, but aren't really needed).

See [@simonw16 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52766245#answer-52766339) for a correct expression.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation of wehere I was going wrong. This is a weak point for me  but this helps!